# Salesforce Summary report formula

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

I have a summary report, I am trying to get the weighted average using formula. The formula should be, if the

```
IF(Survey_Results__c.PG_Relationship_with_IS__c=
"Slightly", 1*RowCount, 0),
IF(Survey_Results__c.PG_Relationship_with_IS__c=
"Moderately", 2*RowCount, 0),
IF(Survey_Results__c.PG_Relationship_with_IS__c=
"Significantly", 3*RowCount, 0),
IF(Survey_Results__c.PG_Relationship_with_IS__c=
"Very significantly", 4*RowCount, 0)
```

[image]

If you see the report, I am getting 0, if I use any one of the formula.

1. Can you please help me how to make this work?
2. How we can check multiple values in one formula?

[image]

Comment: Try to make a formula field like `CASE(PG_Relationship_with_IS__c, 'Slightly', 1, 'Moderately', 2,  'Significantly', 3, 'Very significantly', 4, 0)` and then try something like `Survey_Results__c.My_Weight_Formula__c:MIN * RowCount`

Comment: hi@Oleksiy, I am getting this error. "Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Incorrect parameter type for function 'CASE()'. Expected Object, received Text."

Comment: @Oleksiy, Thanks. It worked. I forgot to create a formula field earlier.

Comment: @Oleksiy, Is there a way I can get Grand Total of weight? I am getting as zero. and Also I need to write formula: Grand Total/Grand Weight. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It might be possible somehow, but I'd give it a small chance figuring this out. Salesforce just isn't capable to do such calculations ((

Comment: @Oleksiy : I got it worked. They calculations are working:) thanks again.

Comment: Glad I was helpful